# Dygraphs - add a shadow to the line

Tags: dygraphs

I am evaluating a few charting packages and Dygraphs is one of these. I've got pretty far in learning how to use it, but one thing I can't do. It's to add shadows to lines. Here is a picture:
[image]

Any idea how to show shadows underneath a blue line and and a sine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in support for this effect, but it would be a reasonable [feature request](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/new).

One workaround would be to implement a [custom plotter](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html) to draw the shadow. So long as you're drawing simple time series, this wouldn't be too hard. But if you're using features like step plots or error bands, it would get more complex.